# How to use @TopicPartition inside @KafkaListener annotation in Spring Boot-Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka

I'm new in Spring-Kafka, I created a class that is called KafkaListeners to read messages from kafka broker. However, the listener didn't print old messages in console. So, I added @TopicPartition annotation on my listener method. But, I encountered an error message as follows:

> An annotation can't be used as the annotations argument

Script:

```
    @KafkaListener(
        topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "demo",
            partitionOffsets = {
                @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0")
            }
        )
    )
    fun listenerDemo(data: Any?){
        println(data)
    }
```

As Image :

[image]

[image]

I saw @TopicPartition usage in java and it is running but it isn't in kotlin.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't answer the Kotlin question, but the reason you don't see old messages with group management is because `auto.offset.reset` is `latest` by default; set it to `earliest` if you want a new consumer to see "old" records. Once a consumer has committed an offset, however, the `auto.offset.reset` property has no meaning; it only applies to new consumer groups.

Comment: See my answer about Kotlin syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kotlin configuration has to be like this:

```
    @KafkaListener(
        topicPartitions = [TopicPartition(topic = "demo",
            partitionOffsets = 
                [PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0")]
        )]
    )
```

Those nested annotations must be without `@` and since those attributes are arrays, we have to specify these nested annotations as arrays as well.

Comment: Yes, it is worked. Thank you very much.